# check if any input value has value in form

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if any of the inputs has a value in a form, the following code works when you refresh the page but not if you have already entered data and you access the page with the form again any ideas:

```
  $('input.input__field').each(function() {
    var inputField = $(this);

    if (inputField.val().trim() !== '') {
      $(inputField).parent().addClass('input--filled');
    }
});
```

Comment: put the add in input event

Comment: sorry? could you elaborate on that don't understand

Comment: have something like this `$('input.input__field').on('input',function() {
    var inputField = $(this);

    if (inputField.val().trim() !== '') {
        $(inputField).parent().addClass('input--filled');
    }
});`